# Oriented undirected edges in directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Some edges are already oriented, some are not. How do I determine how to orient all undirected edges so that each vertex has the same outgoing and incoming degrees, and whether it is even possible to do so?

P.s This graph for example:

[image: Graph]

Comment: If every vertex in the graph has the same amount of outgoing and ingoing edges every edge also has an even degree. If every edge has an even degree there is an eulerian path in the graph. You can use the algorithm of Hierholzer to find the specific eulerian tour.
However you might have to adjust your input a little bit. So for every undirected edge in your original input you could just add tow edges (one for every direction) and mark them as special. Whenever the alogrithm uses one of the special edges both directions of this edge get marked as used.

Comment: Might be a little bit overkill to do it with eulerian path but was the first solution I came up with. However, I think as long as you do not have to implement it, it is not to complicate to argue the corectness of this algorithm.

Comment: Does this anwer your question? Or are you looking for another solution?

Comment: So, I still do not fully understand how we should look for a specific Euler path so that it "balances" the number of incoming and outgoing vertices. This algorithm searches only for any of the Euler paths (Perhaps I misunderstood you).

Comment: So you have modified your input in such way that for every undirected edge in the original input you have two edges (both directions) in your modified input.
Now the algorithm starts looking for an eulerian path in your graph. Every time the algorithm uses one of the edges you can track that. If the algorithm uses one of the edges of the modified input you can additionally track, whick one of the two edges was taken and in the end all those edges will be your result.
However, you also have to make sure that the other edge of teh modied input can not bee taken. You can do that by marking it.

Comment: But what happens if the algorithm takes "wrong" from two edges in the modified graph, and it fails to construct an Euler path?

Comment: If there is no eulerian tour in your graph it is not possible to align the edges as wanted. Because if there is a solution every node in your graph must have an even amount of edges. And if ervery node has an even amount of edges the graph contains an eulerian path.

Comment: I didn't really ask about that. I asked about what if there is some kind of Euler path, but it does not fulfill the necessary conditions for the peaks. How can we find a specific Euler path that would satisfy the condition?
If I have completely incomprehensible explained, I can postorante give an example of what I mean.

Comment: Ok but if you have an euler path, it holds that every vertex as as many incoming as outgoing edges and therefore every euler path you find this way will be a valid solution. So I don't really know what you mean by "not fulfilling the necessary conditions".

Comment: For example, in this graph, if we walk along the edge 0 -> 1 trying to find the Euler path, then we will not be able to walk along every edge. This is my question as well, how to orient the edges to find the Euler path?

Comment: The algorith to find an eulerian path should be good enough to find the right solution. There are algoriths for directed graphs. These would find 2,1,0,3 as a calid solution.